# Is it possible to branch out only some specific folders and create a new branch in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are having one common repository for different applications(Clients).

Common repository develop branch will have some folders like

- Common1
- Common2
- Common3
- Common4

So from the develop branch is it possible to create a new branch for each application / Client

Say Common1 / Common2 in one branch(Branch Name: Client1) and Common3 / Common4 in another
branch(Branch Name : Client2)

So that we can give the branches to separate clients

If new client(Client3 comes in ) I will add Common1 /Common2 / Common3 folder to that branch and will give to that client and so on.

Is this possible?

Comment: You *can*, but anyone with access to the repo can view all branches (though you can restrict write access if desired). I'm guessing you don't want each client to be able to see other client's code, so I think you'll probably be better off with a separate repo per client.

Comment: @TTT , So in that case is it possible to copy folder from Main repo to sub repo. Because common1 will be needed by Client1 and Client2 so that I cant duplicate Common1 folder / code in both the sub repos

Comment: Branches aren't about *files*. Branches—well, branch *names;* the word *branch* is ambiguous—are about finding *commits*. Commits contain files, but not folders: a file named `dir/sub/file.ext`, in a commit, is simply a file named `dir/sub/file.ext`, complete with the slashes. There is no folder `dir`, nor a folder `sub`: that's an artifact of your OS, which requires that a file named `dir/sub/file.ext` be created as a file named `file.ext` in a `sub` in a `dir`.

Comment: This is all just background, and might seem like irrelevant noise, but it's important to realize that Git doesn't store folders at all. It *makes* them, on the fly, when necessary. Git is all about *commits* and you need to think in terms of commits when using Git.